# How to structure many event-like methods?

Tags: events, design-patterns, class-design

The central object of a system I'm developing is getting a bit too unwieldy. The problem is that it can be acted upon in so many different ways. You can:

- Cancel it
- Deny it
- Discard it
- Sell it
- Split it
- Expire it
- ... and plenty more.

I'm considering factorizing those event-like methods away from the class and make it a bit more generic, like a Command pattern. But most of the methods have different parameters, so using a solution like `Run()` or `Execute()` could be a problem perhaps?

Any ideas how to structure this, to make it flexible and simple to add new commands, or actions or what you would like to call them? (I wouldn't call them real events since there are no listeners.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the required parameters for your commands in their constructor ? That way, you can have a parameter-less command.

```
class SellItCommand : ICommand {

  private decimal price;

  SellItCommand(decimal price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  void Execute() {
    // Do whatever needs to be done with in the sell command using this.price
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm considering that. So I'll end up with lots of tiny immutable classes doing one thing? Any pros/cons with this?

Comment: Well, the cons are a risk of class explosionand the pros, each class does one thing, it will be easier to maintain. Without more knowledge of your system, it is hard to tell if there are any gotchas to be aware of with the command pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the parameters, as a single parameter:

```
public class SellCommand: Command {
   Product OwnerProduct;

   ProductCommand (AOwnerProduct)
   {
     this.OwnerProduct = AOwnerProduct;
   }

   public override void Execute(KeyValueArray Parameters)
   {
      double Price = (double)Parameters.ValueofKey("price");
      // do something else
   }
}

public class BuyCommand: Command {
   Product OwnerProduct;

   ProductCommand (AOwnerProduct)
   {
     this.OwnerProduct = AOwnerProduct;
   }

   public override void Execute(KeyValueArray Parameters)
   {
      double Cost = (double)Parameters.ValueofKey("cost");
      // do something else
   }
}


public class Product {
   public void AnyMethod()
   {
     KeyValueArray Parameters =  new KeyValueArray Parameters();
     KeyValueArray.Add("price", "12.5");
   } 
}
```

Its sort of pseudocode, you may like to use the collection libraries that match your programming framework.